# Access denied even though AllowAnonymousAccess is true

Tags: application-pages, anonymous-authentication

I have a weird problem.
I'm making an application page public using

```
protected override bool AllowAnonymousAccess
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I use the same way for other application pages and it's ok, but for this one it doesn't work as it should be. I don't understand why..

Comment: Have you tried to attach a debugger to see if you get to the page, but just have some code which access something which requires a login?

Comment: YES, that was the problem :D.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your application page inherits from UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase and that anonymous access is enabled for the IIS site running the SharePoint application.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work if publishing features are turned ON on the site since they remove LimitedAccess permission level which is required for Anon access. Try on a plain team site with all publishing features OFF.